# C++ problem with Datagram (UDP)winsocket to sendto and recvfrom on the same socket through the loopback adapter

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, winsock, datagram

I am trying to send some data with a udp socket and receive them back on the same socket through windows loopback adatper. In my network properties I set the loopback adapter to have the following ip 192.168.1.1

the recvfrom function returns -1 indicating an error. I also monitor the traffic on the loopback adapter with wireshark and nothing seem to be sent to the loopback adapter, I see no trafic.

Is it true that on windows we can't use the loopback address(127.0.0.1) ? I saw that on some forums, that is why I try to use the loopback adapter.
I also tried to send directly to my own ip, but it gives no better results. Btw it is possible to send to his own ip and get the data back?

I would appreciate any help and just in case, I am new to socket programming.

Below is my code:

```
#define DST "192.168.1.1"

int _tmain(int argc, char* argv[])
{


int    numbytes;
int    bytes_sent;
int    server_sock;
char   send_msg[100];
int    send_msg_length = 100;
char   rcv_msg[100] = { 0 };
int    rcv_msg_length = 100;
int    i;

WSADATA wsaData;   
if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "WSAStartup failed.\n");
    return 1;
}

sockaddr_in to_addr;
sockaddr_in me;

unsigned short Port = 27015;
to_addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
to_addr.sin_port        = htons(Port);
to_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(DST);

me.sin_family           = AF_INET;
me.sin_port             = 0;
me.sin_addr.s_addr      = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
memset( &(me.sin_zero), '\0', 8 );

if ((server_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1)
{
    perror("talker: socket");
}

if ( bind( server_sock, (SOCKADDR *)&me, sizeof( me ) ) == -1)
{
    printf("Error binding/n");
    return 1;
};

int length = sizeof( to_addr );
bytes_sent = sendto(server_sock, send_msg, send_msg_length, 0, (SOCKADDR *)&to_addr, length);
if (bytes_sent == -1)
{
    perror("talker: sendto");
    exit(1);
}

printf("Sent %d bytes to %s\n", bytes_sent, DST);
printf("listener: waiting to recvfrom...\n");

if ( numbytes = recvfrom(server_sock, rcv_msg, rcv_msg_length, 0, (SOCKADDR *)&to_addr, &length ) ) 
{
    perror("recvfrom");
    exit(1);
}

closesocket(server_sock);
WSACleanup();

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding your server socket to port `0`, i.e. asking the OS to assign random port number to it. That has to be the same port you are sending to, `27015` in your case.

Also, you don't have to byte-swap `INADDR_ANY`.

Comment: Yea thx a lot, now I get my data back. I still don't see any traffic on wireshark when i connect to the loopback adapter, any idea why?

Comment: I don't think you have to change loopback address for this to work, `127.0.0.1` should be fine. Don't know about traffic not showing up on local interface - haven't touched Windows for some time.

Comment: Eeeh, no sorry I don't know where I can accept answer, I try to upvote you but I can't as I have not enough points.

Comment: Ok, I found it now , not so eaay to see that on iphone :)

Comment: @Nikolai:  While you can get away with not swapping `INADDR_ANY` it's a poor habit which will confuse you when you use `INADDR_LOOPBACK`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081892/does-sin-addr-s-addr-inaddr-any-need-htonl-at-all

Comment: Note as well that Wireshark can't snoop traffic from the loopback adaptor on Windows (or couldn't last time I checked).